# Can't get python-mode working in Emacs on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, emacs

I can't get python-mode working in Emacs on Mac OS X (I am a relative OS X newbie & not exactly an Elisp expert).

I installed the Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/. The version is reported as "GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2011-12-13 on bob.porkrind.org"

I have the following lines in my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/progmodes")
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.py$" . python-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq interpreter-mode-alist
      (cons '("python" . python-mode) interpreter-mode-alist))
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Editing Mode" t)
```

But whenever I load up a file with the `.py` extension, the mode still remains `Fundamental`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's how I got python-mode (`python-mode.el`, not `python.elc`) working on my install:

1. Downloaded [python-mode.el-6.0.8.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+download) to my `~/Downloads` folder.
2. `pushd /Emacs/directory/with/other/.el/files` (this directory was actually `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/progmodes/` on my machine)
3. `tar -xzf ~/Downloads/python-mode.el-6.0.8.tar.gz`
4. `popd`
5. Then added the following lines to my `~/.emacs` file (replacing all other references to python or python-mode):

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "/Emacs/directory/with/other/.el/files/python-mode.el-6.0.8")
   (setq py-install-directory "/Emacs/directory/with/other/.el/files/python-mode.el-6.0.8")
   (require 'python-mode)
   ```

The only remaining issue now — which was created by the successful install & activation of `python-mode` — is that an unnecessary buffer also gets created with an interactive invocation of the Python interpreter.

Thanks to @Ribtoks for the link that got me started along the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your .emacs file (also, set path to your python-mode. mine is in .emacs.d/ folder) before your python-lisp-includes code

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/python-mode")
(require 'python-mode)
```

Look for files here
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=PythonMode;id=PythonProgrammingInEmacs

Comment: There's no `python-mode.(el|elc)` in my `~/.emacs.d/` directory.

Comment: @markvgti than you can look for it in the internet.. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your load path is right, could you try adding this line right after it?

```
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
```

I'm using emacs from Linux. Dont know if this might be the difference with Aquamacs.
Anyway, there's a [page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizeAquamacs#toc14) for configuring Aquamacs with Python mode. 
Didnt read it, but maybe it should be worth reading for any related tip.. :)

Comment: Didn't work. Getting _File mode specification error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "python-mode")_

There is a `python.elc` in the path mentioned earlier (`/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/progmodes`)

Comment: Does the path added using `'load-path` have to point to the actual `.el|.elc` file, or just the directory in which the relevant `.el|.elc` file is contained?

Comment: It should point to the file.
For me its works like this, loading directly the file...
    (load "~/.emacs.d/py_mode/6.0.6python-mode.el") 

(See edits on the answer)

Answer (score 0):

auto-creating of an python-shell instance should be fixed in current trunk, resp. latest release

if not, please file a report at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode